# Capture response using SSH command

Tags: ssh

I'm using sshpass and ssh to send a command to a Linux box, and then disconnect.  The command is sent ok, but I don't get the response I expect.  I noticed that upon login the host sends 5 blank lines, then a 5 line banner.

It appears that the ssh command (when passing a command as a parameter) is returning only the first blank line.  Is there a way to cause it to return ALL text?  (or wait for 5 seconds to capture all text before returning)

---

Command looks like this, and capturing response into Bash variable

```
RESPONSE=$(sshpass .... ssh..... "my command")
```

Comment: What code did you use to capture the text?

Comment: Running from a bash script, I added line above

Comment: Please add the full script (sans password). It's entirely possible that the actual problem happened quite a bit earlier.

Comment: Voting to close; if it's edited to add more information I'll vote reopen.

Answer (score 1):

This allowed me to capture the output of the host

```
user@host /tmp# output=$(ssh login@domain "ls")
login@domain's password:
user@host /tmp# echo $output
file1
file2
file3
```

Another solution, possibly even better as it records everything including banner, not just output:

```
ssh user@domain |tee /tmp/output
```

Where /tmp/output contains the full log.

Comment: Dont forget to use double quote with variables as the contents of the variable may include spaces. `echo ”$output"`

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  How long does SSH wait for a response before closing the connection? Maybe my host is slow?

Comment: Can you log into the host with ssh outside of the bash script (on command line)?

Comment: Yes I can - but there is brief delay after the host sends a banner, then the prompt appears.  I'll have to investigate the delay - perhaps that's a clue

Answer (score 1):

To capture the wall you have to create an expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sshpass -p XXX ssh login@domain
expect "$ "
send "ls\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

and capture the output like this

```
OUTPUT=$(expect expectscript)
```

You should use ssh keys.